GPO, cannot set Item-Level Targetting to User (grayed out)
When creating a new Drive Map, and using Item-Level Targetting to target a security group, It defaults to Computers in group, instead of users in group. The Users section is grayed out.
Other Drive Maps I have still show the Users being selected, but its grayed out there also.

This does not seem to be just a problem with Drive Maps. Printers also  have this, and I expect the other options to also have this.
How can I fix this?

This will happen if you have Windows Update KB5041578 installed.
Uninstalling this update will fix the issue, but you can also work around it.
Here are two methods, depending on your situation.

If you already have a Drive Map, right-click it, select Copy, then right-click, select Paste.
Edit the new Drive Map to your needs.

From a computer not affected by this bug, Create the DriveMap and use XML export and import to transfer it over.


It is also possible to create a new Drive map with only the Computer Group selected, export that as XML (or according to a source on reddit drag that to your desktop to get a file) edit it to correct the problem and import the XML or paste the file back into GPO and then remove the old item. I haven't tested this last method though.
